# What is the word to refer to customers who are no longer visiting?

Tags: vocabulary

For customers who still visit frequently, we call them "existing customers". But what do we call those who used to visit, but are no longer coming back?

I'm thinking of terms like "left customers", "ex-customers", "quitting customers"... but they all sound odd to me.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I would perhaps just say lost custom(ers)? Possible to use estranged customers? However the latter does not sound right to me

Comment: *Former customers*?

Comment: Inactive customers, old customers?

Comment: @bib of course, its so obvious, dont know why it didnt spring to mind

Comment: I'd just say *previous* customers, but *lapsed* might add a sense of the historic.

Comment: They *are* customers, still. Those are just not "active" (at present, or anymore) -- better to call the "existing" ones as "active" customers to distinguish from the others. Depending on context, "lost customers" has been used apart from other such descriptions.

Comment: I found this because I develop a customer acquisition system and I have to be very careful about nudging users in the wrong direction.  I use "lapsed customers" because it isn't final and provokes "Maybe if I just give them a call..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with ***Past***-customers...

Examples of use seem prevalent:

[image]